# AspNetBoilerplate Ajax repose error despite 200 response code

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Im having some unexpected problems with a ajax call within the aspnetboilerplate system.

I want to return an array to populate a select list,

The ajax call fires correctly and hits the controller. The controller returns the results as a model successfully, except it continually hits an error.

here is my controller action:

```
public async Task<List<DialectDto>> GetAllDialects(int Id)
{
    var language = await _languageAppService.GetLanguage(Id);

    return language.Dialects;
}
```

Here is my ajax call
           var languageId = $(this).val();

```
 abp.ui.setBusy('#textContainer');



        $.ajax({
            url: abp.appPath + 'Language/GetAllDialects?Id=' + languageId,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (content) {

                abp.ui.clearBusy('#textContainer');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                abp.ui.clearBusy('#textContainer');
            }
 });
```

Inspecting the return object in javascript clearly shows a 200 result with all the data  in the responsetext property.

Other posts suggest that the content type isnt specified correctly and this is likely the a json parse error. Ive tried setting the dataType property to both 'json' and 'text' but still get the same response

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: 1. Can you please post the error you are receiving? If the error is in action method please use try catch statement. And confirm if you are sending the right response.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem in one project. I'm using AspNet Boilerplate on a web .NET5 project.

Just like in your case I had a call to a controller method in my JavaScript code that returned 200 code, while in JS I had a parse error and then the "success" code was not executed. To solve the problem I changed the return value of my controller method. I used to return an IActionResult value (i.e. the Ok() value for ASP.NET). Then I changed the return value to another object (a DTO in my case) and everything went right afterwards. For reference:

Before (not working):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method([FromBody] YourClass input)
{
    // method logic

    return Ok();
}
```

After (working):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<DtoClass> Method([FromBody] YourClass input)
{
    // method logic

    return dtoClass;
}
```

I also tested that returning a JsonResult class works with the framework just like this (e.g. return new JsonResult(result)).

Hope this helps somebody else in the future :)